# How to make the Firefox Picture-in-Picture window lose focus using keaboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, firefox

When I watch a video in the Firefox Picture-in-Picture mode and want to switch to another window with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, that window does come in front, but the focus is still on the Picture-in-Picture window which remains on top. How can I avoid this behavior without closing the Picture-in-Picture window?

Comment: Noticing the same misbehavior with Chrome's picture-in-picture window. I believe it's a Gnome bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a [Gnome bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5162). Switching to another desktop environment or waiting for a fix are the current options.

Answer (score 0):

The way PiP works is inconsistent with your wishes. It is not possible to prevent this behaviour without either:

- Turning it off  or
- Dismissing it.

There are two ways to dismiss it if you wish to retain use of the feature:

- To show controls, tap the PiP player.
- To dismiss the PiP player, select the `X` in the corner of the video PiP
  player.

[reference](https://support.google.com/youtubetv/answer/9175324?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdismiss-picture-in-picture%2Cturn-off-picture-in-picture%2Chow-picture-in-picture-works)

Comment: That's pretty sad! Why can it lose focus by mouse but not by keyboard? ☹

Comment: I doubt that Picture-in-Picture cannot lose focus by keyboard, because on Windows it behaves exactly the way I want!